# Using "mod" operator

Tags: delphi, math, integer, modulo

I am trying to display whenever I need to do a certain action in my `for` loop every 300th iteration (makes sense?)

Here is in code what I want to do, but not the way I want to do it:

```
for I := 0 to 2000 do
  Begin
   if I = 300 then
   DoAnAction;

   if I = 600 then
   DoAnAction

   if I = 900 then
   DoAnAction

   if I = 1200 ......... Same action all over, but I don't want to check all those conditions!
  End;
```

So I have been told to use the `mod` operator, and this is how I do it:

```
for I := 0 to 2000 do
 Begin
  if I mod 300 = 299 then
  DoAnAction;
 End;
```

**However**, the results using the above snippet would do the action at 299, 599, 899 ....

How can I make it do it at 300, 600, 900 ...... using the Mod operator? (And doing `if I mod 300 = 300` did not work)

Thanks!

Comment: 0 mod 300 = 300 mod 300 = 0. i mod n is in the range [0..n-1].

Comment: Wow, so many answers! Well, I guess the first one gets the mark..

Comment: give the tick to the best one, not the one which appeared fastest

Comment: @David - Which one do you recommend?

Comment: @David - I've pissed off many people on here, thats why I ask the expert first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for I := 0 to 2000 do
 Begin
  if (I mod 300 = 0) and (I > 0) then
    DoAnAction;
 End;
```

Though your previous version does makes sense too, I=299 is the 300th pass ;)

EDIT: `I mod 300 = 300` would not work because `mod` operator returns the remainder of devision, which is by definition will be in range `0..299`

Comment: Isn't there a rumor about that the condition-check that has the highest possibility of returning false when using the `and` operator, should be checked first? In this snippet, I > 0 is true almost every time. Of course it would not really matter in this case as it wont take long to check that, but again, I just overheard that. Correct me if I am wrong please. :)

Comment: I didn't thought of such optimizations, of course it will make more sense to exchange the checks. Should I edit my answer? :)

Comment: @Krom - Well, I got what I need, but if others find use of the question, it may be a good idea. :)

Comment: @Jeff: If you're worried about that level of optimization, don't. Instead, change your loop to run from `1 to 2000`, and it can never run when the counter is `0`.

Comment: @Ken - I am not worried, just wanted to make sure I was actually right :P

Comment: @Ken White: That will be a mistake since loop function depends on I value to be in 0..N range, not 1..N.

Comment: @Krom: the for loop can begin and end with any integer values.

Comment: @Argalatyr: I should clarify, I was talking about THE loop in question. It was made to be 0..2000, not 1..2000.

Answer (score 4):

The `mod` operator returns the rest of the division. So if you want to do it every 300th iteration, use `i mod 300 = 0`.

`I mod 300 = 300` doesn't make sense, as there can't be a division by 300 leaving a rest of 300.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
if i mod 300 = 0
```

The modulus operator returns the remainder of a division.

Here's an example to help you out. Drop a TMemo on a blank new form, and put this in the `FormCreate` evemt:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
const
  Output = 'i mod %d = %d';
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format(Output, [i, i mod 5]));
end;
```

Run it, and look at the output in the memo.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(I <> 0) AND ((I mod 300) = 0)`.

Comment: `mod` returns the rest of a division. There can't be a division by `x` leaving a rest of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This image display what to change]

`procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:REal;
begin
   i:=strtofloat(edit1.Text);
   if i mod 5 = 0  then
   begin
           label1.Caption:='Кратно 5';
        end
           else
         begin
           label1.Caption:='Не кратно 5';
           end;
end;`

Comment: This contribution does not appear to be an answer to the question asked. If you have a new question, please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.